# Comparing double values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, double

I've a `double` variable called `x`.
In the code, `x` gets assigned a value of `0.1` and I check it in an 'if' statement comparing `x` and `0.1`

```
if (x==0.1)
{
----
}
```

Unfortunately it does not enter the `if` statement

1. Should I use `Double` or `double`?
2. What's the reason behind this? Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Can you add your declaration of the double, please?

Comment: A comprehensive reading about the subject: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's a standard problem due to how the computer stores floating point values. Search here for "floating point problem" and you'll find tons of information.

In short – a float/double can't store `0.1` precisely. It will always be a little off.

You can try using the `decimal` type which stores numbers in decimal notation. Thus `0.1` will be representable precisely.

---

You wanted to know the reason:

Float/double are stored as binary fractions, not decimal fractions. To illustrate:

`12.34` in decimal notation (what we use) means

```
1 * 101 + 2 * 100 + 3 * 10-1 + 4 * 10-2
```

The computer stores floating point numbers in the same way, except it uses base `2`: `10.01` means

```
1 * 21 + 0 * 20 + 0 * 2-1 + 1 * 2-2
```

Now, you probably know that there are some numbers that cannot be represented fully with our decimal notation. For example, `1/3` in decimal notation is `0.3333333…`. The same thing happens in binary notation, except that the numbers that cannot be represented precisely are different. Among them is the number `1/10`. In binary notation that is `0.000110011001100…`.

Since the binary notation cannot store it precisely, it is stored in a rounded-off way. Hence your problem.

Comment: I completely understand what you say above. BUT, why, if he wrote `x = 0.01;` to assign `x` and then compared to the literal `0.01`, wouldn't the actual underlying binary value of `x` and `0.01` be the same (again, assuming no calculations were used to assign `x`). Therefore, `(x == 0.01)` ought to work, should it not? Once you perform some arithmetic with `x`, all bets are off, though. Also, I would've been more explicit: `if (x == 0.01d)` to explicitly state that `0.01` is a double (and not converting `0.01` from `float` to `double`)--which may have been the problem.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight: i cannot reproduce what you say(.NET 4). I get `true` if i compare `0.01` with `0.01`.

Comment: Yes, if you do `x = 0.01; if ( x == 0.01)` then the comparison should be true. Well, assuming there aren't any implicit float-to-double datatype conversions (though maybe even then). But the OP didn't specify how he got the first `0.01`. It's quite likely that it does come from a calculation.

Comment: @Vilx - True, the OP doesn't  state how the `x` value got assigned. If the value is assigned over iterative calculations (meaning, the final result is ~0.01), then this could be "expected". :)

Comment: For me, it return true? why?

Comment: @Imad - Read above.

Comment: @Vilx- Thank you very much :)

Comment: `if(scheduledEnqueueTimeInMin != 0){ }` where `scheduledEnqueueTimeInMin` is assigned as `bool scheduledEnqueueTimeInMin=0` while checking like above I am getting below sonar issue `Do not check floating point inequality with exact values, use a range instead.`

Answer (score 64):

`double` and `Double` are the same (`double` is an alias for `Double`) and can be used interchangeably.

The problem with comparing a double with another value is that doubles are approximate values, not exact values. So when you set `x` to `0.1` it may in reality be stored as `0.100000001` or something like that.

Instead of checking for equality, you should check that the difference is less than a defined minimum difference (tolerance). Something like:

```
if (Math.Abs(x - 0.1) < 0.0000001)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 38):

You need a combination of `Math.Abs` on `X-Y` and a `value` to compare with.

You can use following Extension method approach

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
    {
        const double _3 = 0.001;
        const double _4 = 0.0001;
        const double _5 = 0.00001;
        const double _6 = 0.000001;
        const double _7 = 0.0000001;

        public static bool Equals3DigitPrecision(this double left, double right)
        {
            return Math.Abs(left - right) < _3;
        }

        public static bool Equals4DigitPrecision(this double left, double right)
        {
            return Math.Abs(left - right) < _4;
        }

        ...
```

Since you rarely call methods on double except `ToString` I believe its pretty safe extension.

Then you can compare `x` and `y` like

`if(x.Equals4DigitPrecision(y))`

Comment: It could be nice extension to Double struct !

Answer (score 13):

Comparing floating point number can't always be done precisely because of rounding. To compare

```
(x == .1)
```

the computer really compares

```
(x - .1) vs 0
```

Result of sybtraction can not always be represeted precisely because of how floating point number are represented on the machine. Therefore you get some nonzero value and the condition evaluates to `false`.

To overcome this compare

```
Math.Abs(x- .1) vs some very small threshold ( like 1E-9)
```

Comment: Could you illustrate clearly with an example???

What is the solution so that i need to change my statement??

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s.aspx):

> Precision in Comparisons
>   The Equals method should be used with caution, because two apparently equivalent values can be unequal due to the differing precision of the two values. The following example reports that the Double value .3333 and the Double returned by dividing 1 by 3 are unequal.

...

> Rather than comparing for equality, one recommended technique involves defining an acceptable margin of difference between two values (such as .01% of one of the values). If the absolute value of the difference between the two values is less than or equal to that margin, the difference is likely to be due to differences in precision and, therefore, the values are likely to be equal. The following example uses this technique to compare .33333 and 1/3, the two Double values that the previous code example found to be unequal.

So if you really need a double, you should use the techique described on the documentation.
If you can, change it to a decimal. **It' will be slower**, but you won't have this type of problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use `decimal`. It doesn't have this "problem".

Comment: Operations with decimal values are much more slower. We should not always use type decimal just because it "does not have this problem". Both types have own uses.

Answer (score 5):

Official MS help, especially interested "Precision in Comparisons" part in context of the question.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals

```
// Initialize two doubles with apparently identical values
double double1 = .333333;
double double2 = (double) 1/3;
// Define the tolerance for variation in their values
double difference = Math.Abs(double1 * .00001);

// Compare the values
// The output to the console indicates that the two values are equal
if (Math.Abs(double1 - double2) <= difference)
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are equal.");
else
   Console.WriteLine("double1 and double2 are unequal.");
```

Answer (score 3):

`double` (lowercase) is just an alias for `System.Double`, so they are identical.

For the reason, see [Binary floating point and .NET](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint).
In short: a double is not an exact type and a minute difference between "x" and "0.1" will throw it off.

Comment: Edit queue is full, so I'll post the new link here: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint

Answer (score 3):

Exact comparison of floating point values is know to not always work due to the rounding and internal representation issue.

Try imprecise comparison:

```
if (x >= 0.099 && x <= 0.101)
{
}
```

The other alternative is to use the decimal data type.

Answer (score 2):

Double (called float in some languages) is fraut with problems due to rounding issues, it's good only if you need approximate values.

The Decimal data type does what you want.

For reference decimal and Decimal are the same in .NET C#, as are the double and Double types, they both refer to the same type (decimal and double are very different though, as you've seen).

Beware that the Decimal data type has some costs associated with it, so use it with caution if you're looking at loops etc.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Should i use Double or double???

`Double` and `double` is the same thing. `double` is just a C# keyword working as alias for the class `System.Double`
The most common thing is to use the aliases! The same for `string` (`System.String`), `int`(`System.Int32`)

Also see [Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88418.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a tip from the Java code base, try using `.CompareTo` and test for the zero comparison.  This assumes the `.CompareTo` function takes in to account floating point equality in an accurate manner.  For instance,

```
System.Math.PI.CompareTo(System.Math.PI) == 0
```

This predicate should return `true`.

Comment: This is not correct. CompareTo simply uses ==, prone to rounding errors

Comment: @RM : Thanks for this comment that prevented me to make mistake. According to [MSDN documentation on Double.CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=netcore-3.1):  

"Values must be identical to be considered equal. Particularly when floating-point values depend on multiple mathematical operations, it is common for them to lose precision and for their values to be nearly identical except for their least significant digits. Because of this, the return value of the CompareTo method at times may seem surprising."

Answer (score 1):

```
// number of digits to be compared    
public int n = 12 
// n+1 because b/a tends to 1 with n leading digits
public double MyEpsilon { get; } = Math.Pow(10, -(n+1)); 

public bool IsEqual(double a, double b)
{
    // Avoiding division by zero
    if (Math.Abs(a)<= double.Epsilon || Math.Abs(b) <= double.Epsilon)
        return Math.Abs(a - b) <=  double.Epsilon;

    // Comparison
    return Math.Abs(1.0 - a / b) <=  MyEpsilon;
}
```

**Explanation**

The main comparison function done using division a/b which should go toward 1. But why division? it simply puts one number as reference defines the second one. For example

```
a = 0.00000012345
b = 0.00000012346
a/b = 0.999919002
b/a = 1.000081004
(a/b)-1 = 8.099789405475458e-5‬
1-(b/a) = 8.100445524503848e-5‬
```

or

```
a=12345*10^8
b=12346*10^8 
a/b = 0.999919002
b/a = 1.000081004
(a/b)-1 = 8.099789405475458e-5‬
1-(b/a) = 8.100445524503848e-5‬
```

by division we get rid of trailing or leading zeros (or relatively small numbers) that pollute our judgement of number precision. In the example, the comparison is of order 10^-5, and we have 4 number accuracy, because of that in the beginning code I wrote comparison with 10^(n+1) where n is number accuracy.

Comment: Microsoft recommends "you do not use Epsilon when comparing Double values for equality."[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Microsoft mentions "Typically" epsilon is very small to be used for comparison. I did not use it for comparison of a and b. I use it as indication of Zero and avoiding division by zero. The comparison between a and b is done using my custom Epsilon (I change it to MyEpsilon for clarity).

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Valentin Kuzub's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924394/10480776):

we could use a single method that supports providing nth precision number:

```
public static bool EqualsNthDigitPrecision(this double value, double compareTo, int precisionPoint) =>
    Math.Abs(value - compareTo) < Math.Pow(10, -Math.Abs(precisionPoint));
```

Note: This method is built for simplicity without added bulk and not with performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point number representations are notoriously inaccurate because of the way floats are stored internally. E.g. `x` may actually be `0.0999999999` or `0.100000001` and your condition will fail. If you want to determine if floats are equal you need to specify whether they're equal to within a certain tolerance.

I.e.:

```
if(Math.Abs(x - 0.1) < tol) {
   // Do something 
}
```

Comment: And throw in a Math.Abs, in case x is a bit smaller than 0.1. Your code will accept x== -10.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule:

Double representation is good enough in most cases but can miserably fail in some situations. Use decimal values if you need complete precision (as in financial applications).

Most problems with doubles doesn't come from direct comparison, it use to be a result of the accumulation of several math operations which exponentially disturb the value due to rounding and fractional errors (especially with multiplications and divisions).

Check your logic, if the code is:

```
x = 0.1

if (x == 0.1)
```

it should not fail, it's to simple to fail, if X value is calculated by more complex means or operations it's quite possible the ToString method used by the debugger is using an smart rounding, maybe you can do the same (if that's too risky go back to using decimal):

```
if (x.ToString() == "0.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

My extensions method for double comparison:

```
public static bool IsEqual(this double value1, double value2, int precision = 2)
{
    var dif = Math.Abs(Math.Round(value1, precision) - Math.Round(value2, precision));
    while (precision > 0)
    {
        dif *= 10;
        precision--;
    }

    return dif < 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To compare floating point, double or float types, use the specific method of CSharp:

```csharp
if (double1.CompareTo(double2) > 0)
{
    // double1 is greater than double2
}
if (double1.CompareTo(double2) < 0)
{
    // double1 is less than double2
}
if (double1.CompareTo(double2) == 0)
{
    // double1 equals double2
}
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.compareto?view=netcore-3.1