# Linq data type comparison with Double

Tags: c#, linq, rounding

In my Linq query I have a where statement that looks like this

```
&& vio.Bows.Any(nw => nw.XCoordinate.Equals(currVio.XCoordinate)))
```

values are

```
nw.XCoordinate = 4056.48751252685
currVio.XCoordinate = 4056.488
```

Thus the statement of Equals is not working,  what is the easiest way to round?

```
public double XCoordinate { get; set; }
```

Comment: You could not simply use Equals to compare two double number. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the usual way of comparing `double` for proximity by calculating the absolute difference, and comparing it to a small value:

```
Math.Abs(x - y) < 1E-8 // 1E-8 is 0.00000001
```

For example, you can use this approach in a LINQ query like this:

```
&& vio.Bows.Any(nw => Math.Abs(nw.XCoordinate-currVio.XCoordinate) < 0.001)
```

Comment: Just noticed that sometimes the number could be 4056.49

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Then you need to increase the "tolerance" level to something greater than `0.001`, say, `0.005`.

Comment: I understand,  I was trying 0.01 which worked but 0.005 works so much better!  thx again

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Math.Round i.e.:

```
double x = 4056.48751252685;
var newx = Math.Round(x,3);
```

So if you knew you always wanted 3 decimal places you could:

```
&& vio.Bows.Any(nw => Math.Round(nw.XCoordinate,3).Equals(math.Round(currVio.XCoordinate,3))))
```

You could go further and implement [IEquetable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx), and override the equals function, determine which of the two values has the least number of decimal places, round both to that value and compare.