# C# floating point rounding behavior

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

I have been trying to solve a bug that was caused by floating point arithmetic and I reduced it to a simple piece of code that is causing the behavior I don't understand:

```
float one = 1;
float three = 3;

float result = one / three;
Console.WriteLine(result); // prints 0.33333

double back = three * result;

if (back > 1.0)
    Console.WriteLine("larger than one");
else if (back < 1.0)
    Console.WriteLine("less than one");
else
    Console.WriteLine("exactly one");
```

As result rounded to 0.33333, I would expect back to be less that 1, however the output is "larger than one".

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Rounding. Presumably to get that result, the 1/3 in FP is more like 0.333...34, where the 4 is outside the printed range

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing double values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: But why would 0.33333... round to 0.33334? Shouldn't it round to 0.3333 as 3 is less than 5?

Comment: @korhner FP rounding is to the nearest *representable value*. It is not like decimal rounding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using IEEE 754 rounding, let's see what's going on.

In IEEE 754 single-precision floating point, the value of a finite number is dictated by the following:

> -1<sup>sign</sup> × 2<sup>exponent</sup> × (1 + mantissa × 2<sup>-23</sup>)

Where

- *sign* is 0 if positive, otherwise 1;
- *exponent* is a value between -126 and 127 (-127 and 128 are special); and
- *mantissa* is a value between 0 and 8388607 (because it's a 23 bit integer).

If we substitute *sign* with 0 and *exponent* with -2, then we're guaranteed a value between 0.25 and 0.5. Why?

> 1 × 2<sup>-2</sup>

is ¼. The value of

> 1 + mantissa × 2<sup>-23</sup>

is guaranteed to be between 1 and 2, so that's our sign and exponent sorted.

---

Moving on, we can work out fairly quickly that there are two values which can be used as the *mantissa* value: 2796202 and 2796203.

Substituting each in, we get the following two values (one lower, one higher):

- 0.333333313465118408203125 (for *mantissa* = 2796202)
- 0.3333333432674407958984375 (for *mantissa* = 2796203)

The binary representation of the exact value (up to 22 digits) is:

```
1010101010101010101010...
```

As the next digit would be `1`, that would mean the value rounds *up*, not down. For this reason, the higher one has a less significant error than the lower one:

- 0.333333313465118408203125 - ⅓ ≑ -1.987 × 10<sup>-8</sup>
- 0.3333333432674407958984375 - ⅓ ≑ 9.934 × 10<sup>-9</sup>

And since it's larger than the exact value, when multiplied back it will be more than 1. That's why it uses a value that appears off initially -- binary rounding sometimes goes in the opposite direction of decimal rounding.

Comment: Note that if you change "double back = three * result;" to "float back = three * result;" the answer is "exactly one". That would mask the fact that the float version of 1/3 is greater than 1/3.

Answer (score 4):

When I tried above code I found that

```
float result = one / three;
```

statement evaluate the value of `result` as  `0.333333343` not the `0.33333` but console prints it as `0.33333` and then I executed the following statement

```
double back = three * result;
```

it evaluates the `back` as `1.0000000298023224` which is obviously greater than 1 that's why you are getting *"larger than one"*.

Comment: @korhner `float` and `double` do indeed use base 2, and `decimal` does use base 10, but all three of those are floating point types. They're called "floating point" because (roughly) `1.23m` is stored as `123`, plus the position of the `.`. `12.3m` is also stored as `123`, plus a different position of the `.`. The fact that the position of the `.` can vary makes the type a floating point type, hence the name. This is different from fixed-point types, where (for example) some languages' `Currency` type always stores *exactly* four decimals.