# An issue when TextBox is binding to double and enter negative number that little than -1

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue when i binding a textbox to Propery and enter a negative number that is less than -1 - for example -0.45:

the textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Txt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and the property:

```
  double txt;
    public double Txt
    {
        get { return txt; }
        set { txt = value; OnPropertyChanged("Txt"); }
    }
```

it seems when i try to enter -0.54 it changes immediatly to 0, why?

Comment: Do you need your view model to be updated every time text changes as you do now with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` or can you remove that and update view model by default on lost focus? Every time you press a key WPF needs to convert `string` to `double` when posting value to view model and when you type in _-0_ it will parse to _0_

Comment: You could go with text and ValidatesOnDataErrors but it is a bit of work.  Or you could go with a UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit and not update if starts with a - until you get a number other than 0.

Comment: BTW. -045 is not less than -1 ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the convertor that does the job ( So leave your view model as it is- You can use it for both decimal and double). We just need to hold the decimal and -ve position initially:

```
 public class DecimalConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value !=null)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string data = value as string;
        if (data == null)
        {
            return value;
        }
        if (data.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            decimal result;
            //Hold the value if ending with .
            if (data.EndsWith(".") || data.Equals("-0"))
            {
                return Binding.DoNothing;
            }
            if (decimal.TryParse(data, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

So we hold the values or do nothing on binding

Comment: This is exactly what I need to sync my slider control and textbox. Good one!

Comment: An issue is that you cannot write "1.02" this way, since "1.0' is parsed as "1" and you lose the decimal. You need to add another if ()  before the decimal.TryParse:

if (data.EndsWith("0")  && data.Contains(decimalSeparator))
{
    return Binding.DoNothing;
}

Comment: Also the decimal can vary in different cultures between '.' and ',' so use this to get the decimal character:
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

Answer (score 1):

when you enter the decimal value it becomes 0 again so the best way to do this is using the lostfocus trigger:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Txt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Also you need to do this in the view model:

```
public double Txt
    {
        get { return txt; }
        set
        {
            if (!txt.Equals(value))
            {

                txt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Txt");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you use Equals on a double?

Comment: Yes, Just tried it double d1 = 10;
                double d2 = 10;
                bool isequal = d1.Equals(d2);

Comment: The only other way is to use the if (Math.Abs(double1 - double2) <= difference).. i dont need to read it may be you need to see what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: here's a good start:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: i know that i can use lostfocus, but i don't want to use it, doesn't any solution? maybe convereter is good here?

Comment: yes, you can write a converter that will keep on appending the values to a string