# Storing decimal numbers in double? property using updatesourcetrigger as PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using WPF/MVVM.
I am  binding a textbox.Text to a nullable double in view model. UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged and not Lostfocus. Hence the double property will be updated when each digit is entered using Double.Parse(textbox.Text) inside the converter I am using. I am using PropertyChanged and converter here since I need to do some other validation checks.

My issue is I need to enter "1.69".
When I enter "1", it is added as "1" to the property.
Next I enter ".", but it is not added as "1." since double.parse saves the number as "1"

So I can't add decimal numbers. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the converter in the answer on this post might be what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230085/an-issue-when-textbox-is-binding-to-double-and-enter-negative-number-that-little. It looks like it handles the "."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be fine, if you use `StringFormat=\{0:n\}`. For example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FooValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                               StringFormat=\{0:n\}}"/>
```

or just use a converter. For example:

```
<Window.Resources>        
   <helper:DoubleConverter x:Key="DoubleConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...The code omitted for the brevity
<TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,       
                        Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}}"/>
```

and `DoubleConverter`:

```
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       // return an invalid value in case of the value ends with a point
       return value.ToString().EndsWith(".") ? "." : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I learnt that the actual cause behind this is that in TwoWay data binding, it's running a ToString() behind the curtains so no converter will be needed, _but_ that this leads to the aforementioned issue with decimals. So explicitly using a converter seems like the least hacky way and I'm going to go with that. Thanks for that code.

Only change I'd do would be to replace "." with `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator`. For example, here in Sweden the decimal separator is ",".

Answer (score 1):

You could append a `0` before you convert, if the entered string ends with a `.`.

Comment: So you're saying "1." should be added as "10"?

Comment: No. If there is "1." in the TextBox, then append a "0" in order to alter it to "1.0". Then you can convert it to double and store it in your ViewModel. But make sure to not call PropertyChanged, bc otherwise it will also be changed in the view while the user is still typing.

Comment: For that I need to check every time whether the string ends with a "." and keep appending. Will check anyways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a test app using the converter in my comment from this post: [An issue when TextBox is binding to double and enter negative number that little than -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230085/an-issue-when-textbox-is-binding-to-double-and-enter-negative-number-that-little) and it works well for me.

My ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{

    private double? myDouble;
    public double? MyDouble
    {
        get { return myDouble; }
        set
        {
            myDouble = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My test Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DecimalConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="textBox" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Text="{Binding MyDouble, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
            Height="23" 
            Margin="10,185,0,0" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="120"/>

        <TextBox 
            x:Name="textBox1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Text="{Binding MyDouble}"
            Height="23" 
            Margin="10,248,0,0" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

textbox 1 is updated from textbox as expected. Give it a try with Avneesh's converter.

Comment: The full app for the above answer: https://github.com/tim-ashton/WPF-ConverterDemo

Answer (score 0):

This post is 7 years old but seeing as it's still an issue I would like to post my solution to this as well as my understanding of the problem.

The issue is that when you type in a box using updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged is that after each character entered the application will run a parse into a double.  The issue with this is that for things like "1." that are a valid string to parse, it will then return "1" right after you put the decimal in and clear your decimal.

The way I've gotten around this is to bind to a string property, the property then has two backing fields.  One is a double and one is a string. The last needed, if you would like to access the actual double from your view, is a public property that just returns the double backing field.

```
private double _doubleEntry;
private string _stringEntry;
public double DoubleEntry{ get => _doubleEntry; }
public string StringEntry {
    get => _stringEntry;
    set {
        _stringEntry = value;
        if (double.TryParse(value, out double temp))
            _doubleEntry = temp;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StringEntry));
}
```

This will always return the string that the user has entered but only store a double value when it's valid entry.

If you want to then display the value that's in the _doubleEntry variable in the WPF control you will need to bind it's LostFocus to a method that grabs the value from your _doubleEntry and assigns it to the appropriate field for your control.

So your Xaml will look something like this.

```
<TextBox
    LostFocus="StringEntryLostFocus"
    Text="{Binding StringEntry, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And your code for the LostFocus method would be

```
public void StringEntryLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var ctx = DataContext as {YourViewModel};
    if (ctx is null) return;
    var tb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
    if (tb is null) return;
    tb.Text = ctx.TargetTempDouble.ToString();
```

this would go in the code-behind for your user-control or window. (It's not pure MVVM).

Please feel free to post feedback on my answer.  It's my first one on stack overflow.