# if or statement with variables that equal decimals

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an if statement like this

```
decimal var1, var2;
if(var1 == 0.00 || var2 == 0.00)
{
  ...
}
```

Compiler shows error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type `'decimal'` and `'double'`

I have also tried

```
If(var1 = 0.00 || var2 = 0.00){
  //this
}
```

Compiler shows error:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type `'decimal'` and `'double'`

And the third thing i did was make `0.00` a string like `"0.00"` In both the previous methods just to see if it would do anything different.

Comment: You've got the answer probably. But FWIW you shouldn't compare floating point with `==` or `!=`. For decimal that's fine. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Side note: please post complete compile error messages... Which should be something like very self explanatory "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'" in this case.

Comment: I will make sure I do that from now on, I will add it to this just to make it more helpful for anyone looking at this in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0.00` is treated as `double`.You can't use `==` operator with double and decimal directly. You need to cast the values to `decimal` or use `m` literal to make the compiler treat is as decimal instead:

```
if(var1 == 0.00m || var2 == 0.00m)
```

Comment: +1. Note that similar behavior will happen for all comparison between any types that don't have [Implicit Numeric Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) between each other.