# .Net Float error 4 - float(4) = 4.44089209850063E-16

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a sql database, it has a column of floats. In it, the value is "4" and it is displayed a "4" while other values are 2.5, 3.6, all have decimals and those seem to function fine for my issue. But the number without a decimal is different.

I have a basic function

```
  Private Function getScore(scoreValue As Double) As String
    If (scoreValue = 5) Then
        Return "Platinum"
    ElseIf scoreValue >= 4 Then
        Return "Gold"
    ElseIf scoreValue >= 3 Then
        Return "Silver" 
    ElseIf scoreValue >= 2 Then
        Return "Bronze"
    Else
        Return "Unsatisfactory"
    End If

End Function
```

When i pass this "4" that's a float, it returns the "silver" score. How am i to do this function correctly, i can't round the score, so i can't cast it as an integer. I did various debug statements to figure out what was going on and when i output scoreValue - 4 it yielded  4.44089209850063E-16

Comment: I realize, this column should probably be a decimal.

Comment: Did it really give 4.44089209850063E-16? Or did it give -4.44089209850063E-16? In the former case, you have a number larger than 4, and if your function returns "Silver", that seems like a bug. In the latter case, you have a number smaller than 4, and if your function returns "Silver", that seems like the correct result. Either way, the problem isn't with your function, it's with earlier calculations that give you such misleadingly close-to-integer numbers.

Comment: 4 - myfloat gave the positive number, so my number is essentially 3.999999999999

Comment: Ah, okay, it's just that you have it the wrong way around in the question: you have scoreValue - 4 in your question rather than 4 - scoreValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to change the whole application and are focused on this method, you can use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx):

```
scoreValue = Math.Round(scoreValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

This will round the number, but not to an integer - it should keep some meaningful scale.

Either way, you should also consider the `scoreValue = 5` condition: it might also fail. See also: [Comparing double values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398753/7586)

Comment: That was what i ended up doing, but it felt hackish (though i wasn't aware of the midpointrounding either, so that was good to know). If i were to edit it, should it be a decimal then for a small number like this (the values should be between 0 and 5 and really 2 decimals is all that is significant)

Comment: @Brandon - Well, it is somewhat hackish. For this code you can also round to `int` and have a specific check for 5.