# C# Compare two double with .Equals()

Tags: c#, compare, double

I use ReShaper and when I compare two double values with ==, it suggests that I should use the Math. ABS method with a tolerance. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator.html

This example

```
double d = 0.0;
double d2 = 0.0;
if (d == d2)
{
    /* some code */
}
```

is then converted to

```
double d = 0.0;
double d2 = 0.0;
if (Math.Abs(d - d2) < TOLERANCE)
{
    /* some code */
}
```

But I think it's really complicated for a developer to think about the right tolerance. So I thought this may be implemented in the Double.Equals() method.

But this method is implemented like so

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj is Double)) { 
        return false;
    } 
    double temp = ((Double)obj).m_value; 
    // This code below is written this way for performance reasons i.e the != and == check is intentional.
    if (temp == m_value) { 
        return true;
    }
    return IsNaN(temp) && IsNaN(m_value);
}

public bool Equals(Double obj)
{ 
    if (obj == m_value) {
        return true; 
    } 
    return IsNaN(obj) && IsNaN(m_value);
}
```

**Why is that? And what is the correct way to compare double values?**

Comment: Why not use decimal ? if(double1 < double2) will give you a problem always for really close values

Comment: If you find it difficult for a *developer* to get a tolerance, how should the *.NET-framework* decide on any as it has far less knowledge of what you consider to be equal.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I thought they may use double.Epsilon as the default tolerance or would that be a bad idea?

Comment: It says in the documentation you provided that Epsilon is considered too low to be the default tolerance in the majority of cases.

Comment: Have a look e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp).

Comment: _And what is the correct way to compare double values_ - there is no way - you cannot checks `double` for **real** equality. Do not use `double` for cases where you need check for equality, use `decimal` instead

Comment: `double.Equals` is intended to be compatible with various things that assume `Equals` is a equivalence relation, so it definitely cannot use a tolerance

Comment: I'm not so sure that `decimal` is the answer. The real issue is why you where comparing doubles in the first place. That shouldn't have occurred. Take a long critical look at what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could create an extension method

```
public static class DoubleExtension 
{
    public static bool AlmostEqualTo(this double value1, double value2)
    {
        return Math.Abs(value1 - value2) < 0.0000001; 
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
doubleValue.AlmostEqualTo(doubleValue2)
```

Comment: This method can be very dangerous for big project where everybody uses this extension method. Imagine situation where `value1.EqualDouble(value2) == true` so then if `value1.EqualDouble(value3) == true` it easy to assume that `value2.EqualDouble(value3) == true` too - but it is not in some cases. So suggest at least change name to something more informative `CloseTo` fro example

Comment: Thanks! the Double.Equals Method that C# has doesn't implement an epsilon so testing something like 0.5 == 0.5 gave me a bad flag. By the way I modified your method for a normal method instead of an extension, something like: public static bool AlmostEqualTo(double value1, double value2)
  {
    return Math.Abs(value1 - value2) < 0.0000001; 
  }

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex.equals?view=net-6.0

> If the obj parameter is not a Complex object, but it is a data type
> for which an implicit conversion is defined, the Equals(Object) method
> converts obj to a Complex object whose real part is equal to the value
> of obj and whose imaginary part is equal to zero before it performs
> the comparison. The following example illustrates this by finding that
> a complex number and a double-precision floating-point value are
> equal.

```
double n1 = 16.33;
System.Numerics.Complex c1 =
new System.Numerics.Complex(16.33, 0);
Console.WriteLine(c1.Equals(n1));               // Returns true.
```

Answer (score -2):

I ended up using

```
double piConstant = 3.142;
double piFractional = 7/22;
if(piConstatnt.String("{0:0.00}")==piFractional.String("{0:0.00}")
{
    // some code
}
```

This lets me control the precision by setting the desired string format.
https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

In case you want more info on Equals method from microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=net-5.0