# How to bind different UI controls to different objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two UI controls whose properties I want to bind to properties of two different objects. Here is my XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Canvas Width="300" Height="200">
        <Slider x:Name="_slider1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="272"/>

        <Slider x:Name="_slider2" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="36" Width="272"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfBindingDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Binding binding1 = new Binding("MyProperty1");
            binding1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding1.Source = _myObject1;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(_slider1, Slider.ValueProperty, binding1);

            Binding binding2 = new Binding("MyProperty2");
            binding2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding2.Source = _myObject1;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(_slider2, Slider.ValueProperty, binding2);
        }

        MyClass1 _myObject1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 _myObject2 = new MyClass2();
    }

    public class MyClass1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); }

        public double MyProperty1 {get; set}
    }

    public class MyClass2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); }

        public double MyProperty2 {get; set}
    }
}
```

As you can see, I bind UI control properties (`Value` in this case) to different objects properties in code (in window constructor) and it works all right, but I find this declaration too bulky and I don't like that it's divided in two parts. I wonder if there is more compact way to declare this kind of binding in XAML, something like

```
<Slider x:Name="_slider1" Value="{Binding MyProperty1, Source=_myObject1}"/>
<Slider x:Name="_slider2" Value="{Binding MyProperty2, Source=_myObject2}"/>
```

I've tried to play with `Source`, `RelativeSource` and `ElementName` properties, but failed to make it work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you just change the `DataContext` of the 2 `Slider` for pointing the right object and property of relative class ?

Comment: Why not to use _myObject1.MyProperty1 and _myObject2.MyProperty2 for binding? Where _myObject# is a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your `_myObject1` and `_myObject2` as properties (pascal case), you can bind them.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyClass1 MyObject1 { get; } = new MyClass1();
    public MyClass2 MyObject2 { get; } = new MyClass2();
}
```

You can use [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to refer to the `MainWindow` to bind them.

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="200">
   <Slider Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="272" Value="{Binding MyObject1.MyProperty1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
   <Slider Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="36" Width="272" Value="{Binding MyObject2.MyProperty2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
</Canvas>
```

You can of course also set the data context to the window itself, so you do not have to use `RelativeSource` each time, see @Clemens answer for a code-behind sample.

It is also possible to set the `DataContext` in XAML instead.

```
<Window ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Then the bindings would be simplified the same way.

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="200" DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel}">
   <Slider Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="272" Value="{Binding MyObject1.MyProperty1}"/>
   <Slider Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="36" Width="272" Value="{Binding MyObject2.MyProperty2}"/>
</Canvas>
```

Although this works, **it is a bad approach**. It mixes user interface components - the `MainWindow` - with your business data or logic. You should separate them to achieve better testablility and maintainability. There is a common pattern called MVVM that is focused on separating your view from your data. You can read an introduction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

You should create a view model for your main window that exposes the data through properties. You should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` here, if you intend to change the properties.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
   public MainWindowViewModel()
   {
      MyObject1 = new MyClass1();
      MyObject2 = new MyClass2();
   }

   public MyClass1 MyObject1 { get; }
   public MyClass2 MyObject2 { get; }
}
```

You can create and assign the view model as `DataContext` directly.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Window.DataContext>
       <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!-- ...other markup. -->
</Window>
```

Alternatively, you can create an instance and assign it in code-behind.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then the bindings would look like this.

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="200">
   <Slider Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="272" Value="{Binding MyObject1.MyProperty1}"/>
   <Slider Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="36" Width="272" Value="{Binding MyObject2.MyProperty2}"/>
</Canvas>
```

---

As a side note, your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is useless, unless you actually compare values to assign for equality and call `OnPropertyChanged` in setters.

```
public class MyClass1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private double _myProperty1;

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
   { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); }

   public double MyProperty1
   {
      get => _myProperty1;
      set
      {
         if (Math.Abs(_myProperty1 - value) < /* ...your comparison epsilon here. */)
            return;

         _myProperty1 = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

In the specific case of floating point numbers, you should compare against an epsilon, see [Comparing double values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp) for more information.

Comment: @yadda Sorry for the initial edits, it should be consistent now :-D . The combination of a typical monday, daylight savings time and the severe lack of coffee pays its toll.