# C# Math.Ceiling bug or not?

Tags: c#, ceil

I do not know why Ceiling behave like in the below image

Why is processingFee != Settings.PaymentProcessingFeeInPercentage * prizesSum ?

[View image at full size](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/3950/csharpceilingproblem.png)

[alt text http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/3950/csharpceilingproblem.png](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/3950/csharpceilingproblem.png)

Comment: I didnt understand your question, but be sure that Math.Ceiling() wants a parameter decimal or double

Comment: What is the problem here? processingFee is equals to 131, which seem ok.

Comment: @Serkan - Math.Ceiling accepts both decimal and double.

Comment: @Pierre - The error is the result in processingFee should be 130, not 131.

Comment: LOL@self. I tried to scroll to the right.

Comment: k now I see the usual floating point problem that everybody should know about. This question is then a duplicate of many other before it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise)

Comment: Tip: When you encounter a problem like this, you should ask your question with the starting assumption that it is not a bug (i.e. ask "why doesn't this behave like I expect?" rather than, "is this broken?").  This is particularly true when you're not doing anything particularly weird and are using a common namespace.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your percentage isn't *actually* 0.05. It's a value *close* to 0.05... and probably a little bit more than 0.05. Thus when it's multiplied by 2600, you're getting a value just over 130.0... which is then being "ceilinged" to 131.0.

Using a little tool I wrote a while ago (available from [this page](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/floatingpoint.html) about .NET binary floating point types) it looks like the actual `float` value closest to 0.05 is 0.0500000007450580596923828125. For doubles, it's 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125.

Moral of the story: don't use `float` for this sort of thing - use `decimal`. Or if you're just trying to represent a percentage, if it's okay to *actually* be only accurate to one percent, use an integer value 0-100.

Comment: @pixel3cs: No, don't use `double`, either.  It has the same problems as `float`.  The reason `decimal` avoids these issues is because it is a floating point base 10 number instead of a floating point base 2 number.  In general, `decimal` is going to be your safest choice for working with money, because the internal representation of `decimal` matches the thing you are trying to represent (though less efficiently).

Answer (score 4):

This is a result of the floating point representation of the numbers involved. [See the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding). Probably 0.05 has an infinite base 2 representation as a double, so the value Math.Ceiling actually sees might be slightly larger than 130.

Comment: To be absolutely annoyingly precise: a small (mathematical) integer such as 130 has an accurate finite representation in IEEE floating point numbers (either 32 bit or 64 bit).  What may not be representable in floating point numbers is the (mathematical) real number close to 130 that OP thinks is equal to 130

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing floatng-point imprecision.
The actual base-2 representation of `0.05` is a tiny bit more than `0.05`, so the product is a tiny bit more than `130.0`.
Therefore, `Math.Ceiling` is rounding up.

Change your `float`s and `double`s to `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the internal storage format for a floating point number being inherently inexact when the number is represented in decimal. There are many, many questions on this on Stack Overflow.

The number you are returning is probably something like 130.000000000000001 since the numbers in your calculation can't be represented exactly as a binary floating point number.

Comment: Um, 130 can *certainly* be represented exactly as a binary floating point number. However, 0.05 can't.

Comment: 130 is 10000010 in binary and definitely can be represented exactly as an IEEE754 floating point.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it's probably something to do with floating point precision. In other words, 2600 × 0.05 gives 130.0000...001 rather than 130.

What if you try to round the result first, than call `Math.Ceiling`?

Answer (score 0):

In my compiler, when i lookup the multiply value, it says 130.00000193715096, so the math.ceiling result is ok. The problem is the limited precision of the float data type.

Try using 'double' instead, if it is possible.

Comment: @maxwellb: Not for the value of Settings.PaymentProcessingFeeInPercentage. However, `double` would still give the "wrong" answer. It's simply inappropriate to use `float` or `double` here.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. And yes on the second point, too. What I meant was "double is no more appropraite than float".

Comment: double in this case gives the expected result, anyway, we know the best option is to analyze wich precision is really needed for that data.

Comment: Problem is not limited precision of the float data type, it is lack of understanding of how to use floating point arithmetic.  SO is covered in such lack of understanding.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said that an analysis is necessary. You can even find out that you can do the necessary arithmetic with integers without losing precision (and it can even be faster).

Answer (score 0):

If you use floating point numbers in a large banking operation, don't let me float my money in your bank. Use <strike>decimals, or</strike>  integers of the least common denominator, i.e. cents.

You could however, use a `Math.Round`, to help you use `double`s or `float`s, if you make assumptions about how large your calculations will get. i.e.:

```
double processingFee = Math.Ceiling( Math.Round( 
    Settings.PaymentProcessingFeeInPercentage * prizesSum, 2 ) );
```

Comment: Note that `decimal` in C# is still a floating point type. It's just a floating *decimal* point rather than a floating *binary* point.

Comment: Still "valid" only to a certain number of sigfigs. Good distinction.