# Why is 0.1*10-1 not equal is 0?

Tags: c#, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise)

```
Console.WriteLine(0.5f * 2f);       // 1
Console.WriteLine(0.5f * 2f - 1f);  // 0

Console.WriteLine(0.1f * 10f);      // 1
Console.WriteLine(0.1f * 10f - 1f); // 1.490116E-08
```

Why does `0.1f * 10f - 1f` end up being `1.490116E-08` (`0.0000001490116`)?

Comment: See: ["Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

Comment: See [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise).

Comment: I can't post an answer due to the duplicate flag, but the cause is actually C#'s use of intermediate precision. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30280829/392585

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Wiki: Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). float/double/decimal are *relative precision* types. Not all values (of which there are infinitely many) can be exactly stored. You are seeing the result of this loss of accuracy. This is why it is almost always correct to use `|a - b| < small_delta` for float-point comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Because floating operations are not precise, take a look here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

section `Some other computer representations for non-integral numbers`. 0.1 cannot finitely be represented in base 2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

Read this (explains quite exactly this case): http://www.exploringbinary.com/the-answer-is-one-unless-you-use-floating-point/

Answer (score 0):

Easy, approximations accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

0.5 is representable exactly in floating point, which is why 0.5*2 = 1 exactly.

However, 0.1 is not representable exactly, hence 0.1*10 is not exactly 1.