# Why does 0.1 * 10.0 == 1

Tags: matlab, floating-point

In MATLAB the following is true

```
0.1 * 10.0 == 1
```

But 0.1 is not represented exactly in floating point, so I expected it to not be true.  Did I just get lucky and the error happened to be smaller than eps, so it got rounded to 1?

MATLAB implements IEEE 754, so I think it should apply to all languages.  But this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272803/why-is-0-110-1-not-equal-is-0) makes me think it might be something specific to MATLAB.

Comment: Python does evaluate to true:  >>> 0.99999999999999999 == 1

Comment: You are probably lucky yes.  This post may provide more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Comment: `0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 - 0.6 = 1.110223024625157e-16` while `0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4 - 1.0 =  0.0` (R2012b) :-)

Comment: If I just got lucky, how can I prove it?

Comment: Try increasing the total number of digits of precision for display: `format long g;`, then go and compute your stuff.  On my machine, doing `0.1*10.0` does in fact give me 1, and this is probably because of what you're suspecting.  However, doing something like what @il_raffa does you don't see unless you increase the total number of digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your specific example is true for any language which uses IEEE754 floating point arithmetic (well, 64-bit at least).

The literal `0.1` is exactly

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

`10.0` is exactly 10

Their product is therefore

```
1.000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

The two closest floating point values are:

```
1.0
1.000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062
```

of which the first is closest, so the result is rounded to that.

(I'm not 100% sure what is going on in that example you link to: I suspect it has to do with C# using [higher intermediate precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280829/392585))

In general, however, this sort of thing isn't true. e.g. `0.51255*1e5` isn't 51255 (though MATLAB may lie when printing, try `0.51255*1e5-51255`).