# C# float magically changing value

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have a float holding a very important value, which has to be VERY exact.
The problem I have is I'm changing the value of the float ALWAYS only + and - (No division here).
 After changing the value about 20 times, the value isn't 0.05 as expected, its 0.0499989.
 Why is this? Im not casting the float, I'm not dviding it, but it magically changes from 0.05 to 0.049989.
 I tried `Math.Round(value, 2);` but it doesn't return 0.05 either. What should I do now??

Comment: What do you mean "by design". How can a value change by Design??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise)

Comment: it doesn't magically change it's never 0.05. See the reason for this below

Comment: "I have a float holding a very important value, which has to be VERY exact".  Floating point representation has a wide range, but limited precision.  If you need VERY exact values, you either need a different data type, or you need to be VERY careful with the operations you perform. And it's not necessarily a simple problem to solve. I recall my Numerical Analysis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) classes, which address these issues, as being among the tougher Computer Science classes I took.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Floating point variables in many (if not most) languages only hold an imprecise approximation of the actual value. You can solve the issue in C# by using the `decimal` data type. [See this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It really worked with `decimal`.

Comment: Floats and decimals *both* have representation error, and decimals actually have *larger* average representation error on a per-bit-of-precision basis.  The difference between them is that the quantities which have *zero* representation error in a decimal are quantities that you are likely to want to represent when doing financial calculations.

Answer (score 4):

Float and double values are stored in binary (base 2).
Therefore, they cannot accurately represent numbers like `.3` that have no finite-length representation in binary.

Similarly, a `decimal`, which is stored in base 10, cannot accurately represent numbers like `1/3` that have no finite-length representation in decimal.

You need an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library.

Comment: Arbitrary precision math libraries don't solve this problem, since they use (arbitrary) *finite* precision, and `0.05` cannot be represented in any finite number of binary digits.  What is actually needed is either a symbolic representation, or a rational representation, or for the questioner to educate himself about floating-point and adjust his algorithm appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with float some fractional numbers cannot be exactly represented. Consider using the decimal data type if you only use + and -, you shouldn't have that problem, since decimal uses a base 10 internally.

Answer (score 2):

Just like an `int` variable can only hold integers in a certain range, a `float` can only hold certain values.  `0.05` is not one of them.

If you set an `int` variable to (say) 3.4, it won't actually hold the value 3.4; it will hold that value converted to a representable `int` value: 3.

Similarly, if you set a `float` variable to `0.05`, it won't get that exact value; it will instead get that value converted to the closest value representable as a `float`.  This is what you are seeing.