# .NET's ToString() Number Truncating

Tags: c#, wpf

So, WPF calls ToString() on objects when generating TextColumns in DataGrid and then i found out strange thing about ToString() method:
Check this out :

```
object a = 0.3780000001;//Something like this
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());//Gets truncated in some cases
```

First, I thought it was just rounding, but few times I was able to reproduce such behavior on 
doubles with < 15 digits after dot. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not a .NET bug, just rounding issues.

Comment: Please read the answers. **Double is not an appropriate type to use if you want to deal with both high precision and high accuracy. Use `decimal`.**

Comment: OK, thanks, I just thought some WPF solution to always show 17 digits after dot when rendering cell exists

Comment: @taras: The point is that this has nothing to do with WPF or the UI *at all*. It's simply not there in the *data type*.

Comment: Now I understand this, numbers with >17 digits after dot simply are getting rounded when ToString() is called

Comment: @taras: No, that's not correct. There is no rounding happening when you call `ToString()`, as values with >17 significant digits (according to the spec, actually, >15 significant digits) *are truncated when they're stored*. There's no rounding taking place because the value simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined on the [MSDN page for System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx), the `double` type only contains a maximum of fifteen digits of precision. Even though it maintains 17 internally, your figure contains 18 significant digits; this is outside the range of `System.Double`.

Answer (score 9):

To the computer, 0.378 and 0.378000...0001 are the same number. See this question: [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise)

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not true. `0.378` and `0.378....0001` may *or may not* have the same in-memory representation. In the case of a sufficiently-large `decimal` in .NET, they're certainly different. In the case of any of the floating-point types in .NET, they're the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use `decimal` instead of `float` for a more precise type.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `Double.ToString()` truncates to 15 digits after the dot, but if you really want to use the `double` data type and you need those 2 extra digits, you can use th "G17" formatting string:

```
double x = 3.1415926535897932;

string pi = x.ToString("G17");
```

This will give you a string with the full 17 digits.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't assume (so fast) that you found a bug in something as crucial as C#'s ToString implementation.

The behaviour you're experiencing is caused by the fact that a float is imprecisely stored in computer memory (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise/753955#753955)).

Answer (score 1):

maybe the number format's accuracy range doesn't contain that number? (ie, float only has accuracy to a few significant figures)

Answer (score 1):

If you're data-binding the value, you can supply a ValueConverter which formats the number any way you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: Easier to use the `FormatString` property on the binding.

Answer (score 1):

Set a to be an Decimal and it will print it correctly!

```
decimal a = 0.378000000000000001m;
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
```

Comment: I can not modify the WPF's sources

Comment: convert it to a decimal..decimal x = Decimal.Parse("0.378000000000000001");

Answer (score 0):

You could have a common decimal format setting to use all the time.

eg

```
 object a = 0.378000000000000001;
 Console.WriteLine(a.ToString(Settings.DecimalFormat));
```