# What is wrong with the following code?

Tags: c

//A program that calculates the amount of money in a bank account after n years

```
#include <stdio.h>

double bank(double money, double apy, int years);

int main() {

double money1, apy1;
int years1;

printf("How much money is currently in your bank account? ");
scanf("%d", &money1);

printf("How many years will this money stay in your account? ");
scanf("%d",&years1); 

printf("What is your APY? ");
scanf("%d", &apy1); 

int bank1 = bank(money1, apy1, years1);

printf("Your grand total after %d will be $%d \n", years1, bank1); 


system ("PAUSE");
return 0;   
}


double bank(double money, double apy, int years) {

 if(years <= 0) 
    return money;

 else
    return bank(money*apy, apy, years-1);

 }
```

Comment: Seriously? "What is wrong with this code?" is your entire "question"?

Comment: Is it not compiling? Is it failing in some other way? I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Its not calculating the total correctly.

Comment: @Krysten you might want to edit your question to ask exactly why its not calculating the total correctly.

Comment: I'm surprised that it's calculating at all!

Comment: www.homeworkoverflow.com

Comment: not homework... but I got it fixed with a very simple suggestion. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
scanf("%d", &money1);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &money1);
```

and change:

```
scanf("%d", &apy1);
```

to:

```
scanf("%lf", &apy1);
```

And while you're at it you might want to add some printfs to help with debugging (assuming you don't have a source level debugger.)

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
return bank(money*apy, apy, years-1);
```

should probably be

```
return bank(money*(1+apy), apy, years-1);
```

since the interest you earn should be added to the existing amount. Otherwise your total amount would be reducing each year.

Comment: Also the return from bank is being cast to int but I'm not sure if this is deliberate or not.

Comment: that doesn't seem to give me the desire output

Answer (score 2):

Another one is :

```
double bank(double money, double apy, int years);
```

Returns a double, **but**

```
int bank1 = bank(money1, apy1, years1);
```

You place the result in an int.

Answer (score 1):

[**You should never use floating point in financial calculations.**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Floating point is inherently uncapable of representing 10-base values precisely, which means that you will suffer from rounding errors and unequalities, which is unacceptable in finances (among others).

[This has been discussed in detail many times on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-imprecise). The issue is not language specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call you function in the following way:

```
int bank1 = bank(money1, 1+apy1/100., years1);
```

Otherwise you'll have a LOT of money :)