# float.TryParse() rounded the value in C#

Tags: c#

while trying to parse variable to float with following parameter float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fValue),

the value=6666.77777 is rounded of to 6666.778.

can anyone help, i don't want my value to be rounded.

Comment: If you want to maintain *decimal* places, use a `decimal`.

Comment: What do you want? An infinitely long string?

Comment: Where do you see the value of `6666.778`? Probably the problem of the output format. But anyway you shall acknowledge that [floating points always have precision errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise).

Answer (score 3):

`float` only has around 6 significant digits. Note that digits *before* the decimal point count too. `double` has higher precision in that regard (around 16):

```
PS> [float]::Parse('6666,77777')
6666.778
PS> [double]::Parse('6666,77777')
6666.77777
```

But as others noted, this is just an approximate value because it cannot be represented exactly in base 2. If you need decimal exactness (e.g. for money values) then use a `decimal`. For most other things binary floating point (i.e. `float` and `double`) should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

That is because value 666.77777 cannot be represented in the binary form floating point numbers use - the actual number contains more binary digits than the floating point has room for. The resulting number is the closest approximation.

> Rounding is used when the exact result of a floating-point operation
>   (or a conversion to floating-point format) would need more digits than
>   there are digits in the significand. IEEE 754 requires correct
>   rounding: that is, the rounded result is as if infinitely precise
>   arithmetic was used to compute the value and then rounded (although in
>   implementation only three extra bits are needed to ensure this). There
>   are several different rounding schemes (or rounding modes).
>   Historically, truncation was the typical approach. Since the
>   introduction of IEEE 754, the default method (round to nearest, ties
>   to even, sometimes called Banker's Rounding) is more commonly used.

You should consider using `double` if you need more precision, or `decimal` if you need even more than that, though they too suffer from precision loss at some point.

Comment: That's not the reason here :-). It *is* rounding.

Comment: It *appears* to be rounding, but actually it is not ;)

Comment: See my answer. `float` just doesn't have enough significant digits to deal with that number. So the ones that don't fit are cut (rounded) off. This is completely orthogonal to the issue that binary floating point cannot represent some (most) numbers exactly.

Comment: You are correct. I guess I was taught outdated information - that it was truncated, not rounded.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) or [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) to support higher precision:

> **float**: Approximately ±1.5 x 10-45 to ±3.4 x 1038 with 7 significant figures
>
> **double**: Approximately ±5.0 x 10-324 to ±1.7 x 10308 with 15 or 16 significant figures
>
> **decimal**: Approximately ±1.0 x 10-28 to ±7.9 x 1028 with 28 or 29 significant figures

Try this piece of code snippet instead:

```
double fValue;
double.TryParse("6666.77777", NumberStyles.Double, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fValue);
```

OR

```
decimal fValue;
decimal.TryParse("6666.77777", NumberStyles.Decimal, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `decimal` if you need higher precision.