# C# Getting strange results for a simple math operations

Tags: c#, math, console-application

I have noticed for some strange behavior while adding two doubles, sometimes it works correct, and sometimes not!

Here is the first example:

```
double num1 = 0.1 + 0.7; //Guess the result?
```

Easy - 0.8 !!! or not?

Look at the strange result:

[image]

And guess what, the if statement is going inside the else block, and prints the `num1` - and no, it doesn't prints 0.799999999999993, it prints 0.8.

So I have gone one more step forward and tried this code:

```
if (0.1 + 0.7 == 0.8) //Returns false ??
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct");
}
```

OK, strange, but now I found the correct way, it should use f (float). As I remember double has many spaces, so it can contain higher numbers, maybe this is the cause.

```
float num2 = 0.1f + 0.7f;

if (num2 == 0.8f) //Perfect - finally works !!!
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(num2);
}
```

But now, I try this - and again it returns false, why?

```
if (0.1f + 0.7f == 0.8f) //Returns false :(
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct");
}
```

The watch results when debugging it:

[image]

Can someone explain me what's wrong here? Are those bugs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise)

Comment: @MichaC The way the question asked is completely different and also it's not the same.

Comment: Of cause you put a lot more effort into the question, but at the end, it is the same thing. It is just because of the fact that floating point arithmetic in C# is not precise. Which was answered 1000 times on this site already ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is not precise. You should read the article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you want your calculations to be precise in a decimal sense, you should use the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) type, where `0.1m + 0.7m == 0.8m` is `true`. You should note that `decimal` uses floating point numbers just like `float` and `double`, except that the base is 10, not 2. Since dealing with base 2 is so much easier and highly-optimized, `decimal` is much slower. It also has its own inaccuracies, it's only precise when dealing with numbers that can be represented in a short number of decimal digits (like `0.7` and `0.1`), making it good for financial data.

Another useful article to understand floating point numbers is [Wikipedia's Double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 2):

internally, a double is stored in bits, in base-2.
All integers can be represented exactly in base-2, but when it comes to fractions, it;s another matter all together.

The same way that we cannot precisely respresent the result of 1/3 in our decimal system, in a binary system you cannot represent all fractions. Since decimal is base-10, it is easy to represent x/10 in decimal, but in base-2, it is impossible for some x.

So whenever you use doubles, always be aware of some rounding errors.

For this reason, doubles are not to be used whenever exact numbers are required, as with monetary amounts.

Comment: In the second paragraph, surely you mean "is impossible for some `x`". For example, 5/10 = 1/2 can be represented exactly in base 2 floating point.

Comment: But the statement is true: 0.1 in binary has the same issue that 1/3 has in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Call the Math.Round method to ensure that both values have the same precision. The following example modifies a previous example to use this approach so that two fractional values are equivalent:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      double value1 = .333333333333333;
      double value2 = 1.0/3;
      int precision = 7;
      value1 = Math.Round(value1, precision);
      value2 = Math.Round(value2, precision);
      Console.WriteLine("{0:R} = {1:R}: {2}", value1, value2, value1.Equals(value2));
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//        0.3333333 = 0.3333333: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383871/Demystify-Csharp-floating-point-equality-and-relat

Floating values are only approximations. To compare two floating point values you need to check the difference between them. The difference cannot be greater than `float.Epsilon`

Use this to compare these values:

```cs
bool AlmostEqualDoubles(double nVal1, double nVal2, int nPrecision = 6)
{
   nPrecision = Math.Max(Math.Min(16, nPrecision), 0);
   double nEpsilon = 1.0;
   for (int i = 0; i < nPrecision; i++) nEpsilon *= 0.1;       
   return (nVal2 - nEpsilon) < nVal1 && nVal1 < (nVal2 + nEpsilon);
}
```

Comment: "Floating values are only approximations" isn't strictly true. A better way of stating this would be that many decimal values don't map precisely into IEEE floating point numbers. However, values that can be factorized using powers of 2 will have a precise value when mapped to floating point numbers (e.g. 4, 2, 1, .5, .25, .125 etc). The same problem occurs in the decimal world with numbers such  as 1/3 etc.