# parse float from string

Tags: c#, parsing

I have some problem with parsing float value from string.
Problem is with decimal part of value, here is example:

```
var tmp = "263148,21";
var ftmp = float.Parse(tmp); //263148.219
```

I tried some other values, but I don't figured out, from what reason are some decimal values incorrect.

Comment: its "263148,21" or "263148.21"?

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj Is that matter as a _value_? No. That's only matter for representation.

Comment: any specific reason to declare tmp as var instead of actual data type?

Comment: Try `double`.  32 bit floating point numbers can only store about 7 to 8 significant decimal digits,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise)

Comment: @hypheni, `var` is used because the types are obvious and thus putting the actual datatype creates noise and reduces readability.

Comment: In our country we use comma for decimal separator. No, can't use double because in xsd schema is datatype defined as float.

Comment: @davidm, then you'll have to put up with the inaccuracies.

Comment: You need to use your country culture. As far as I know , (comma) separator for decimal is being used in NL (Dutch) culture. Thus include culture information in parse method.

Comment: @Savaratkar - this has nothing to do with culture - the OP's code is working correctly, they are asking why a `float` representation of this value is not accurate.

Comment: @MattJones Oh I missed that point.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have anything to do with the comma in the OP's code - instead, this question is about a `float` value not accurately representing a real number.

Floating point numbers are limited in their precision. For really precise numbers you should use `double` instead.

See also this answer: [why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise?lq=1) and have a look at this for more information: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Any explanation for the down vote? This answer is correct in it's observation of the inherent precision limitations of the `float` type. If you have a problem with my answer, please leave a comment.

Comment: I can't believe how people are voting on this question. This answer is the only one that addresses the actual problem. This question has nothing to do with culture-specific formatting. I can't understand why those answers get up-voted.

Comment: @Matt Jones posted some good articles completely explaining why float type numbers like 0.1 are represented as something like 0.099999955.  It's how the number is represented in binary that causes this.  Some say never use float in calculations but there are many places to use float, but just like in Chemistry or Physics you have to pay attention to your significant figures and margin of error

Answer (score 1):

```
var tmp = "263148,21";
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
var ftmp = double.Parse(tmp, culture);
```

You have to use `double` instead of `float`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers and comments, this is related to floating point precision.

Consider using [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) if you need to have the exact same decimals or to leverage rounding errors. But please note that this type is much more heavy weight (128 bits) and might not be suited for your case.

```
var tmp = "263148,21";
var dtmp = Decimal.Parse(tmp); //263148.21
```