# Improper conversion from float to int C #?

Tags: c#, web

I can not understand why is done differently. Example below.

```
float val = 0.94f;
int i = (int) ( val * 100);
```

The result of 93?

```
float val = 0.94f;
float val1 = val * 100;
int i = (int) (val1);
```

The result of 94?

Comment: Check your code -  ( * val 100)

Comment: float is the problem, `(int)(0.94 * 100);` works as expected but not `(int)(0.94f * 100);`

Comment: Strangely enough: In a Debug build you get the "wrong" behaviour, in a Release build, all is well. This is most likely due to the fact that the compiler optimizes both versions to the same code in a Release build.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise  , similar answer the problem is float that has bad precision and mixing it with int isn't making it better.

Comment: Use *rounding up*, not *truncation*: `int i = (int) ( val * 100 + 0.5);` note `+ 0.5`

Comment: use double , if you want to solve the problem , but I guess this is a more theoretical question?

Comment: @Thorarins: `Double` *doesn't solve* the problem: `0.93999999f` or `0.9399999999999999d` cause the same error. Use *rounding* (i.e. `+0.5`) not *truncation*

Comment: yes rounding is the way to go , but for this case double solves it