# Math.Abs weird behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, math

I am doing following equation but the result is not as expected

```
   double dasdas = Math.Abs(3.2 - 1.9);
```

The result is

```
1.3000000000000003
```

However the correct result should be

```
1.3
```

What may be the reason of this?

c# 4.5.2

[image]

Comment: use  `Math.Round(Math.Abs(3.2 - 1.9), 15);` if you want to keep the type as double. or keep `14` decimals instead of `15` to make it safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using a double - which is a floating point.  These *by definition* this cannot store the exact number.

You need to use `Decimal`.

Take at look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Read About Floating Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: decimal is also a floating point number and also cannot store the EXACT number, it just that it has base of 10 and will be fine keeping the sum result of two decimals precisely :)

Comment: Are you sure? The C Sharp Spec makes a distinction between floats and decimals see section 4.1.6 and 4.1.7 `"The decimal type has greater precision but smaller range than the floating-point types."`

Comment: Floating points can store many numbers exactly. For example binary floating points can store `1.25` exactly, but not `1.1`. Decimal floating points (including the .net decimal type) can store `1.1` exactly but not `1/3`.

Comment: as a general rule, the same problem exists in Decimal

Comment: well, if you read about how it's implementes you'll see that's exatly what it is... it has mantissa, exponent, and sign :P

Comment: Okay cool - so it's just fractional values it has trouble storing and despite documentation it's a float under the hood

Comment: well I would say the specification is fairly clear about what is it, it's just this sentence that is a bit unprecise :) But yeap, they didnt really invent anything to go around this problem. It's just that decimal base is more suitable for many operations.

Comment: @mikus Indeed. For example, `Console.WriteLine(3m*(1m/3m));` will NOT print `1`. I'd say that `Decimal` is really intended for financial calculations, and would not be normally used for scientific or engineering calculation, particularly if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `decimal`:

```
decimal dasdas = Math.Abs(3.2m - 1.9m);
```