# Could you explain the behavior of Ceiling method?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, floating-accuracy

I just did a test with LINQPad:

Could you explain me why/how the ceiling method is reacting like this? Notice the 123.12 in the middle.

```
Math.Ceiling(123.121 * 100) / 100 'display 123.13
Math.Ceiling(123.1200000000001 * 100) / 100 'display 123.13
Math.Ceiling(123.12000000000001 * 100) / 100 'display 123.12
Math.Ceiling(123.12000000000002 * 100) / 100 'display 123.13
```

I did the test in VB.NET but it should be the same in C#.

Comment: some form of precision loss

Comment: It's due to the fact that floating point values are inherently imprecise. Please see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise

Comment: That could possibly relate to binary fractions (http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/). Since float are represented by two integers in a division, not every float can be used. That is especially the case when you have a lot of zeros behind the decimal separator followed by 1 (like in your examples). In that case the flow get rounded. For example 123.12000000000001 might be rounded to 123.12 before it gets passed to the ceiling method.

Comment: Bear in mind that with `123.0000000001` you are defining a `Double` variable. You can increase the accuracy up to certain level (say... from around 10 decimal positions to the maximum `Decimal` value) by relying on `Decimal` type. You can use it by writing `123.0000000001D`. In any case note that this is only relevant in extreme cases (over 10 decimal positions is not something too common; not even ideal/recommendable).

Comment: @DavidArno Your statement might be easily misunderstood by some people. A couple of days ago I saw an answerer here defending that the fact of using `Double` or `Decimal` was actually relevant while dealing with a number including only 4 decimal digits, what is certainly not. A more correct version of your statement would be: "floating point values are inherently imprecise, for a high enough number of decimal digits".

Comment: @varocarbas. Fair point, well made.

Comment: @varocarbas Since `double` can't represent even `0.1` exactly and `Ceiling` is a discontinuous function, imprecisions can matter, even with only one decimal digit. For example `Math.Ceiling(12 * 0.1 * 10)` is 13 on my machine.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Although you are making a pretty fair point, it is not exactly what my comments (and the original question) was about. When you perform an operation like multiplication, the exact number of decimal digits might not be as clear as it seems. In the case you are proposing, for example: `Dim testVal As Double = 12.0 * 0.1` is not 1.2, but 1.2000000000000002 (notably above my 10 digits recommendation).

Comment: @varocarbas The concept of decimal digits isn't useful when talking about double, since it can only represent power-of-two denominators exactly, so almost all doubles will need many decimal digits if you want to represent them exactly.  If you want an example closer to the OP's question, consider `Math.Ceiling(0.07 * 100)`, which is 8 on my machine.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My first comment was a (kind of) continuation to a discussion I had a couple of days ago regarding rounding certain values (e.g., 1.234). One of the answerers there defended that the fact of being `Double` or `Decimal` did have some effect. This is where my point of number of decimal digits has any meaning; in cases like what the OP is proposing (just assigning a value of x length to a given `Decimal`/`Double` variable) or even by rounding a known `Decimal`/`Double` variable. My point was: don't be afraid of `Double` by default...

Comment: ...`Decimal` is clearly more precise and, consequently, if you are worried about accurate enough decimal results and the size of the values is below the maximum for `Decimal`, you should definetively use this type. But you don't need to be unnecessarily scared of `Double` because of thinking that might provoke unexpected wrong results. The clearer is the picture, the more adequate will be the decisions made on account of such a knowledge; don't you think? Also 10 digits is a rough estimation (= many decimal digits). I cannot think of many situations seriously requiring more than 4 decimals.

Comment: PS: `Dim test0 As Double = 0.07 * 100` equals 7.0000000000000009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is floating point rounding. C# parses 123.12000000000001 and 123.12 as having the same value. 123.12000000000002 is parsed as the next available double.

```
 var bytes = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(123.12));
 // outputs 48-E1-7A-14-AE-C7-5E-40
 var bytes1 = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(123.12000000000001));
 // outputs 48-E1-7A-14-AE-C7-5E-40
 var bytes2 = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(123.12000000000002));
 // outputs 49-E1-7A-14-AE-C7-5E-40
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to floating point rounding rather than Math.Ceiling *per se* which is because floating point values cannot represent all values with 100% accuracy.

Your example is a little contrived anyway because if you try to type `123.12000000000001` in visual studio is changes it to `123.12` because it knows that the value cannot be represented as a double.

Read up on this here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (btw this is not specific to .NET)

To *fix* your issue you can use a decimal value instead of a double. Math.Ceiling has an overload which accepts a decimal (all of these display 123.13):

```
   Debug.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(123.121D * 100) / 100) 
   Debug.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(123.1200000000001D * 100) / 100)
   Debug.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(123.12000000000001D * 100) / 100) 
   Debug.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(123.12000000000002D * 100) / 100)
```

Whether this fix is appropriate of course depends on what level of accuracy you require.

Comment: Isn't decimals notation `M` and not `D`?

Comment: No, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - there is no mention of `M` there as far as I can see

Comment: I was thinking C# my mistake

Answer (score 0):

`Ceiling` returns the number passed to it if they are whole numbers, or else the next highest whole number. So `5.0` stays `5.0` but `5.00001` becomes `6.0`.

So, of the examples, the following are obvious:

```
Math.Ceiling(123.121 * 100) / 100 // Obtain 12312.1, next highest is 12313.0, then divide by 100 is 123.13
Math.Ceiling(123.1200000000001 * 100) / 100 // Likewise
Math.Ceiling(123.12000000000002 * 100) / 100 // Likewise
```

The more confusing one is:

```
Math.Ceiling(123.12000000000001 * 100) / 100 //display 123.12
```

However, let's take a look at:

```
123.12000000000001 * 100 - 12312.0 // returns 0
```

Compared to:

```
123.1200000000001 * 100 - 12312.0 // returns 1.09139364212751E-11
123.12000000000002 * 100 - 12312.0 // returns 1.81898940354586E-12
```

The latter two multiplications have results that are slightly higher than 12312.0, so while `(123.12000000000002 * 100).ToString()` returns `"12312"` the actual number produced by `123.12000000000002 * 100` is mathematically `12312.000000000002` the nearest possible `double` for `123.12000000000002` is is `123.1200000000000181898940354586` so that is what is worked on.

If you are used to only doing decimal arithmetic it may seem strange that `123.12000000000002` is "rounded" to `123.1200000000000181898940354586`, but remember that these numbers are stored in terms of binary values, and rounding depends on the base you are working in.

So while the string representation doesn't indicate it, it is indeed slightly higher than `12312` and so its ceiling is `12313`.

Meanwhile with `123.12000000000001 * 100`, that is mathematically `12312.000000000001` but the nearest possible `double` to `123.12000000000001` is that it can fit into is `123.12`. So that is what is used for the multiplication, and when the result passed to the subsequent call to `Ceiling()` its result is `12312`.

Answer (score -1):

The Ceiling method returns the next higher integer equivalent.

so Ceiling(123.01) = 124

&  Ceiling(123.0) = 123