# Rotate point test is failing. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

This is my Point.cs file that is failing.

```
// Rotates the point counter-clockwise by deg degrees.  For example, applying
// a 90 degree rotation to (1, 0) should give (0, 1).
public void rotate(double deg)
{
    double rotCos = Math.Cos(deg * Math.PI / 180);
    double rotSin = Math.Sin(deg * Math.PI / 180);
    double oldX = x;
    double oldY = y;
    x = oldX * rotCos - oldY * rotSin;
    y = oldX * rotSin + oldY * rotCos;
    Point point = new Point(x, y);
}
```

I run this test and get the result:

> "Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2>. Actual:<2>."

```
[TestMethod]
public void Rotate_Test()
{
    double rotate = -90;
    double i = 4;
    double o = 2;
    Point point = new Point(i, o);
    double expectedX = 2;
    double expectedY = 4;

    point.rotate(rotate);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedX, point.getX());
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedY, point.getY());
}
```

Comment: What do you do with your `Point point = new Point(x, y);`? It gets deleted right away because you didn't assign it to anything...

Comment: I assume it is the final product. really all I need are the x, y points.

Comment: @JayT, Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FCin I removed that line of code and I still get the same result.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't know what you are saying...

Comment: I provided the message I get when running the test. and the test. and the class file. what else am I missing?

Comment: Everything you need should be there. The points are two doubles. The getX() and getY() ONLY return x or y respectively.

Comment: Any how the problem is that the calculated value and the expected values are not the same. after exercising the method under test the value of x in the point turns to `2.0000000000000004` which when compared to `expectedX (2.0)` would fail.

Comment: so then I need to? Reading the comment, the math is supposed to take a 1, 0 point and output 0,1 point. effectively rotating my point around the 0,0 pivot. when I imput a point 1,0. I get "Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<6.12303176911189E-17>."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx

Comment: No. the values returned are ~2.0 and -4 which are different to your expectations

Comment: Well yes. and I do not know why that is but the .001 delta will solve my problem effectively and it is the same as I have used in other test methods. so thanks. Do you know why the math does that? it there a more precise formula for rotating my point around the (0,0) pivot?

Comment: That I do not know. You are going to have to do some research on that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is floating point arithmetic in C# imprecise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles are not exact numbers. They should not be compared for equality without specifying an acceptable difference between them.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Try

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedX, point.getX(), 0.001);
```