# How to solve mathematics error in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I am getting a math error in vb.net.
Even tried in vb6 in my old project.
Even tried in NodeJs.(Asked a friend)
I am doing a simple stuff.

```
Msgbox(3.28 - 3.2)
```

This shows me 0.79999999999996(don't know how many 9 in between but this many for sure.)
Even tried `Msgbox(Format(3.28 - 3.2,"0.00"))`
Still same answer.

In my Vb6 project, I get 7.9999999999996E-02 something.

In nodejs by my friend too get the same 0.7999…96

I need in vb.net so tried using `Format` but no proper answer. Maybe using format in wrong way.

What to do to get 0.08 ?

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/7444103) -- [Why is floating point arithmetic imprecise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/753948/7444103).

Comment: `CDbl(3.28 - 3.2).Tostring("0.##", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))`... but there's also many other ways to do this.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the file — forces you to fix your coding style.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No it's not, The question which you duplicated asked a reason for the error. I wanted a solution.

Comment: @bonny It's usually better to understand *why* something goes wrong so that a solution can be applied. The line `Msgbox(Format(3.28 - 3.2,"0.00"))` does show "0.08". Admittedly, the answer you need if you want to avoid errors from the approximation of base-10 fractions as binary was buried a bit at the end of one of the answers, disguised as a pizza cutter.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are being input by the user in base-10, and the result of the calculation is being displayed to the user in base-10, then you should store the values in `Decimal` variables rather than in `Single` or `Double` variables.  `Decimal` stores numbers in a base-10 (decimal) floating point format whereas `Single` and `Double` store numbers in base-2 (binary) floating point format.  So, if both the input and the output are base-10, a base-10 floating point variable will give you more expected results.

```
' Outputs "0.0799999999999996" because the literals are Double by default
Console.WriteLine(3.28 - 3.2) 

' Outputs "0.08" because the D suffix forces the compiler to interpret the literals as Decimal
Console.WriteLine(3.28D - 3.2D) ' Outputs
```

Floating points are always imprecise, since it's impossible to represent a value accurately in a digital format when it is a repeating decimal--at some point you have to stop the repetition and round it off.  The problem is, which numbers infinitely repeat is different depending which base you are using, so by switching between bases, you can cause the value to be rounded in ways that you weren't necessarily expecting.  So, for instance, even with `Decimal`, you can still get imprecise results, but at least they are rounded in the way that you expect them to be rounded, when doing base-10 math:

```
' Outputs "0.6666666666666666666666666667"
Console.WriteLine(2D / 3D)
```

Comment: Each time I read an explanation it gets a little clearer but this one really helped by pointing out the binary storage versus the base 10 storage. Thank you and upvote.

Comment: You are right but I am not going to change every Double to Decimal in my project. My project deals with numbers. Now if we move ahead and think that the error will come, a solution to again rectify the error would help and not by changing its data types. The Solution below by Greenfrogs, as you said he did rounded off the value and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to floating point arithmetic approximating the values.  This can be solved by using `System.Decimal.Round`

```
Decimal.Round(0.575, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Result: 0.58

Comment: This worked for me.!